# Camel Case property names in json files are not getting mapped to Java Object

Tags: json, jackson, fasterxml

I have a json object with property names like: `itemsRequired`, `sortable_list`. And in my ObjectMapper, I have

```
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

With this `sortable_list` gets mapped to appropriate property in POJO but `itemsRequired` is ignored. While if I remove the `PropertyNamingStrategy`, then `itemsRequired` works and `sortable_list` don't. What should be done if I want both to work together?

I am using fasterxml lib. I have also tried codehaus's jackson with same result.

---

Update: The POJO is as follows,

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class CreateList extends Header {
    private String question;
    private String placeholder;
    private String help;
    private int itemsRequired;
    private List<String> list;

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

And the JSON is,

```
"create": {
    "heading": "Activities Available to You",
    "question": "List at least four activities at school and in your community that you may want to try out.\n",
    "placeholder": "List an activity",
    "help": "You can only have 10 list items",
    "list": [],
    "items_required": 4
  }
```

Everything works fine, if I have the JSON as above. But things do not work when I change the JSON to,

```
"create": {
    "heading": "Activities Available to You",
    "question": "List at least four activities at school and in your community that you may want to try out.\n",
    "placeholder": "List an activity",
    "help": "You can only have 10 list items",
    "list": [],
    "itemsRequired": 4
  }
```

itemsRequired is ignored in latter case.

I would like it to work in both cases, whether it is named as `items_required` or `itemsRequired`.

Comment: You can use JsonProperty annotation (http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html) Could you also show to us your POJO class and example JSON?

Comment: As mentioned in below answer, we changed our naming convention to use underscores rather than camel-case.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you should probably use explicit annotation for entries that you do not want to be modified.
I don't know why code above wouldn't work: it seems like it should. You are also correct in using Jackson 2.x version (com.fasterxml package); there is no benefit trying to use older 1.x versions.

You may want to file a bug report: this could be a bug. But to know this, bit of sample code is needed; perhaps there is another explanation to the problem.

Comment: Updated the question with more details.

Comment: Thinking this through, it won't work with naming strategies, because they start with POJO property name, derive expected JSON name; and no aliases can be defined. One possible work-around does exist: you could specify different name for field and setter -- one using underscores, other camel-case. Ugly, but would work for deserialization (serialization could be problematic, producing 2 properties)

Comment: I would have thought of doing that, but for now we have decided to make our json naming consistent to use underscores and not camel-case.

Comment: Makes sense, if and when doable. And makes things more consistent so is probably good anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @JsonProperty. If you donot like idea of adding annotation to target class you can use always use [Mixins](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations), if you want to have few if them as snake case and other camelCase.Since mixins allows you to add property names to class without actually editing 
target class, mostly in case of third party classes.

But I would preffer [custom naming strategy](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/PropertyNamingStrategy)

since it allow you to have strategy which can parse both and will be registered with ObjectMapper, will help you to avoid maintaining mixins,JsonProperty etc.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).